# can i treat panel data as pooled data?

Tags: econometrics, stata, data

I'm working with panel data on Stata. However, I want to perform the ROC analysis and for what I know it is way simpler using the "logit" command instead of "xtlogit". Thus, my question is: is it correct if I consider my panel data as pooled data (and thus I use the logit command instead of xtlogit)?